# How can I send a notification whenever I make a new Firebase Hosting deployment?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-hosting

I have a small, internal Firebase App used for work. It is critical that users of this app always receive the most recently deployed code. If they have the page open and I make a new deployment to Firebase, I want to send a message to all of these clients that I can receive in my client-side code and then display a notification for. I am assuming that I would use Firebase Cloud Messaging to dispatch the message.

Is there a good way for me to do this with Firebase? Is there an event for this in the Cloud Functions feature? I've scoured the documentation but I cannot find any reference to an event that would let me do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time being, I am having Travis CI use `curl` to send an API request that will update a `latest_commit_hash` property in my database. My client-side code will observe this value and notify users appropriately when it changes.

**Update**: Turns out that I don't even need to use `curl`, I can just do the following:

```
firebase database:set --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" --data \"$TRAVIS_COMMIT\" --confirm /deploy_commit_hash
```

Comment: If you're using Firebase database (`latest_commit_hash` is a node, right?), then you could make use of [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to *listen* for that change, then trigger an FCM message.

Comment: Yes, `latest_commit_hash` is a node. I've realized that involving FCM is making this more complex than it needs to be. I've updated my answer post with the approach I am now taking.